# Empty cell using a checkbox in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this function in Google Sheets that adds a timestamp to a specific cell if the checkbox is set to TRUE. I want to take it to the next level by clearing the same cell (format must be kept) if the checkbox is set to FALSE.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
   var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
   columnToWatch = 1,
   columnToStamp = 2,
      if (e.range.columnStart !== columnToWatch ||  !e.value || excluded.indexOf(sheet.getName()) > -1) return;
   sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp)
       .setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MMMM"); }
```

Comment: Why do you want to clear the cell? Do you ever want the user to write inside of that cell manually?

Comment: Because I want to be able to add or remove the timestamp by simply using the checkbox.

Comment: Is the number of rows you want timestamps on infinite? Or is it a fairly fixed number of rows?

Comment: The number is infinite

Comment: You are going to want to modify the way you are creating timestamps, try clicking a bunch of checkboxes as quick as you can. Would you be ok with a solution that requires you to manually drag the timestamp formula down?

Comment: Would rather include all in one formula. I am currently trying to add the Else statement but without success

Comment: Did you try clicking your checkboxes very quickly?

Comment: Yes but nothing happens

Comment: About how many checkboxes do you expect to have checked off? 100,1k, 100k?

Comment: I think less than 5k

Comment: excluded is undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //e.source.toast('flag0');
  if(excluded.indexOf(sh.getName())>-1)return;
  if (e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast('flag1');
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MMMM"); 
  }
  if (e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value=="FALSE") {
    //e.source.toast('flag2');
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(''); 
  }
}
```